# Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: java, mysql

при выполнении запроса возникает ошибка Operand should contain 1 column(s),
в чем может быть дело?

```
public List<Comment> read (int id) throws SQLException {

    Statement statement = null;



    List<Comment> commentList = new LinkedList<>();

    String sql = "SELECT (user_name, comment_content) FROM comments WHERE poster_id = '"+id+"'  ";


    try{

        statement = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);



        while (resultSet.next()){
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            comment.setUserName(resultSet.getString(1));
            comment.setContent(resultSet.getString(2));

            commentList.add(comment);
        }



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new SQLException(e);
    }

    return commentList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить скобки в `SELECT (user_name, comment_content) FROM`

*Без скобок*

```
String sql = "SELECT user_name, comment_content FROM comments WHERE poster_id = '"+id+"'  ";
```